# Call CMD to run GPUpdate in Powershell

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell-5.1

I am trying to remotely force a GPUpdate by means of invoke-command as Invoke-GPUpdate is not available to me in my environment.  I was messing around with it one day and it executed as expected, but since then I have been unable to get it to work.  It may be environment related, but I just wanted to double check what I have is correct, or there are alternatives I am unaware of.  I am currently just trying to call CMD for it to run "Gpupdate /force" but it just hangs on a blank line after execution.

Doing

```
& cmd.exe /c "msg * hi"
```

as expected brings up a popup saying hi.

I have tried pretty much every permutation of the below:

```
& cmd.exe /c 'gpupdate /force'
cmd.exe /c 'gpupdate /force'
cmd.exe 'gpupdate /force'
cmd 'gpupdate /force'
& cmd 'gpupdate /force'
```

Eventually I would like it to be something like this

```
Invoke-Command -computername $Computer -Credentials $Cred -Scriptblock{& cmd.exe /c 'gpupdate /force'}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the Syntax?

Comment: Why did you change the syntax from double quotes, (which worked), to single quotes?

Comment: You know you can just simply use `gpupdate /force` from within powershell?

This means you should be able to do: `Invoke-Command -computername $Computer -Credentials $Cred -Scriptblock { gpupdate /force }`

Comment: I feel foolish haha.  @Minkulai's solution is what I ended up going with.  The syntax I was using to research a solution just kept coming up with cmd or cmd.exe and my initial syntax for running the invoke-command had something like 'invoke-command -computername $comp -scriptblock{cmd gpupdate /force' so I was still stuck on thinkin cmd had to be called.  I will add an answer although I wish I could set Minkulai's as the answer.

Comment: @Compo Correct me if I am wrong, but single/double quotes don't usually make a huge difference.  I think in certain situations it does, but from what I can tell they are mostly interchangeable and in this instance either way works for me.

Comment: @ThePostMan I recommend reading the Microsoft PowerShell documentation page [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for getting knowledge about the __big__ difference between `'single quoted string'` and `"double quoted string"`. The difference is as big as it is for Linux shell interpreters. `cmd.exe` does not support quoting a string with `'` at all. `'` is for `cmd.exe` a literal character, except in __set__ of a `for /F` command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Minkulai pointed out the obvious, but I didn't want to leave this unanswered.  This is what I ended up using:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {GPUpdate /Force}`

I am running this cmdlet from an elevated script already so the `-Credentials $Cred` portion in @Minkulai's comment is not necessary, but may be needed if your script does not have rights to run.

Comment: Happy to help! Unfortunately I couldn't post my answer at the time but I could copy/paste it as answer in few hours, if it's still fine :)